# Live graph based on logs file results for response time

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, graph

I am starting to make one web app which will be responsible for showing the response time , successful calls, failure calls(based on the response code) graph based of the log file. file content will be like below:

```
10.49.41.104 - - [06/Aug/2015:11:49:05 +0200] "POST /mosa/roamingdata/roamingdataservice/1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 424 *Sec=0/MiSec=102316*
```

So in this line we have response time for the call that is made on this URL. I have never worked on graph thing in java and i am also not sure if i can achieve this in servlet or any other framework. Can some one just give me the starting point from should i start.

graphs will be took like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/chart-overview.htm

(Btw. the picture you want to draw is called [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart), the term [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) is used for something else in programming / computer science.)